# Appending the counts of lists to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a large list, which I separated into small sized lists which have elements of occurrences of 1s and 0s, randomly.

Also, the first two lists are made with different parameters from the last two.

```
Example:
list_of_lists[0] =[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
list_of_lists[1] =[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
list_of_lists[2] =[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
list_of_lists[3] =[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
```

I would like to count the occurrences of 1s and 0s in each list, and append them into a dictionary to plot the occurrences.

My trial is as follows:

```
counts_each = dict()
for i in range(4): #all 4 lists
  for k in list_of_lists[i]: #elements of the lists
    counts_each[k] = counts_each.get(k, 0) + 1
print(counts_each)
```

which calculates the general occurrences of the 1s and 0s for the al lists:

```
{0: 16, 1: 24}
```

If I do:

```
list_counts = []
for i in range(4): 
  counts_each = dict()
  for k in list_of_lists[i]: 
    counts_each[k] = counts_each.get(k, 0) + 1
    list_counts.append(counts_each)
print(list_counts)
```

It does not accumulate all of the counts:

```
[{0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {0: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {1: 10},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7},
 {0: 3, 1: 7}]
```

I would be glad to have some insights of what I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let the collections module do all the counting work for you.

```py
from collections import Counter

list_of_lists = [[] for _ in range(4)]
list_of_lists[0] =[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
list_of_lists[1] =[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
list_of_lists[2] =[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
list_of_lists[3] =[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]

counters = [Counter(l) for l in list_of_lists]
print(*counters, sep="\n")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Counter({1: 7, 0: 3})
Counter({0: 10})
Counter({1: 10})
Counter({1: 7, 0: 3})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Dict Comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), given your nested list:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]
```

use it in this way:

```
{ idx: {0: lst.count(0), 1: lst.count(1)} for idx, lst in enumerate(list_of_lists) }
#=> {0: {0: 3, 1: 7}, 1: {0: 10, 1: 0}, 2: {0: 0, 1: 10}, 3: {0: 3, 1: 7}}
```

In the above case I used the index as a key, but you could just use a list comprehension to get a list of dictionaries:

```
[ {0: lst.count(0), 1: lst.count(1)} for lst in list_of_lists ]
#=> [{0: 3, 1: 7}, {0: 10, 1: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 10}, {0: 3, 1: 7}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris Doyle's answer is excellent, but perhaps your goal is to understand the problem with your solution, specifically.

You have not included your *expected* output.  If I am correct that your issue with your current solution is the repetition of the counts, and you want an output like this:

```
[{1: 7, 0: 3}, {0: 10}, {1: 10}, {0: 3, 1: 7}]
```

Then the issue appears to be with the indenting of the line `list_counts.append(counts_each)`.  You are doing this each time through the `k` loop (looping through the items in the list) when I think you want to do it only after finishing the count for a given list:

```
list_counts = []
for i in range(4):
  counts_each = dict()
  for k in list_of_lists[i]:
    counts_each[k] = counts_each.get(k, 0) + 1
  list_counts.append(counts_each)

print(list_counts)
```